# Angularjs ngCsp example of forbidddened practices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, content-security-policy

In angularJS doc for ngCsp (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp), there are two lines desc what not to do... But I have no idea what they exactly are!

```
don't use Function constructor to generate optimized value getters
don't inject custom stylesheet into the document
```

I can't find examples on its doc.

May I have any one demonstrate some examples for AngularJS?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the exact same thing, but could only find the following for 1) don't use Function constructor to generate optimized value getters:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11465

and the AngularJS documentation also specifies that:

> AngularJS uses Function(string) generated functions as a speed optimization. Applying the ngCsp directive will cause Angular to use CSP compatibility mode. When this mode is on AngularJS will evaluate all expressions up to 30% slower than in non-CSP mode, but no security violations will be raised.

So it seems that you won't need to worry about the Function constructor part all too much, your performance will just be slowed down.

For 2) don't inject custom stylesheet into the document, ng-hide, ng-show, and ng-cloak is a pretty good example that angular uses as an "inline stylesheet," for example:

```html
<p ng-hide="true">This is the ng-hide ngCsp example.</p>
<p ng-init="buttonClicked = false" ng-show="buttonClicked">This is the ng-show ngCsp example.</p>
<button ng-click="buttonClicked = !buttonClicked">Click to Show/Hide</button>
```

won't work when you include ng-csp in your html.   Won't work meaning the first p tag will show because ng-hide is disabled and the button won't toggle the second p tag as ng-show is disabled.

Both ng-hide / ng-show can be enabled by importing this stylesheet: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular-csp.css

Hope this helps, from what I understand, these 2 precautions help protect against Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) Attacks.